# How to make WCF callback to clients consequences?

Tags: .net, wcf, callback

I have a WCF service and several .NET Windows form clients, which a client contains some sub-form running scanner data from a website.

My problems is: How to make all sub-form get data consequence? (second by second). Because when WCF Service callback, it call immediately to all client's method call back at the same time

The client can have 1 to 5 sub-form.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are asking. Are you using wsDualHttpBinding? You seem to be saying that you want to have all clients receive their callbacks at different times.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to stream data?  To have it send an updated response every second?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean all the sub-form of a client start a Method() after 1 second, for example: Client1 has 2 sub-form: form1 start at 10:10:10, form2 start at 10:10:11; Client 2 has 3 sub-form: form1 start at 10:10:12, form2 start at 10:10:13, form3 start at 10:10:14... and so on.... so in the website that I want to grab data, I will scan it every second of a minute (60 times/ min)